# Range for nargs in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script which merges multiple video and audio files. Now I have a parameter which allows four values:

```
# -A FILENAME LANGUAGE POSITION SPEED
$ script.py [... more parameters ...] -A audio.mp3 eng -1 1 [... more parameters ...]
```

Now I want the third and fourth to be optional. Currently I have two ideas but maybe there is a better solution:

- Set `nargs` to `+` and throw an error if 1 or more than 4 parameters are supplied. Maybe the `type` parameter can catch this. Problem would be that it isn't visible in the help that 2 to 4 values are required.
- Have 4 different parameters for all combinations. This would allow to have the position optional. Problem is that I then need four parameter names.

The parameter also might appear multiple times (`action` is `append`).

Comment: Does your script accept positional arguments, or just arguments proceeded by a flag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using `argparse` so positional arguments are possible, also I'm not sure if this would work with my question.

Comment: I'm asking because if you give `nargs='+'` and you give that option last, `argparse` won't be able to tell it's arguments from your positional arguments. Since you have positional arguments, your best bet is probably four different options or allowing the parameter to appear multiple times.

Comment: Or, you could have the user give a comma separated list, so that only one argument is given, and then you split it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having `-A` take a single, comma-separated string (or use the delimiter of your choice), and supply a custom metavar for the help message.

```
def av_file_type(str):
    data = tuple(str.split(","))
    n = len(data)
    if n < 2:
        raise ArgumentError("Too few arguments")
    elif n == 2:
        return data + (default_position, default_speed)
    elif n == 3:
        return data + (default_speed,)
    elif n == 4:
        return data
    else:
        return ArgumentError("Too many arguments")

p.add_argument("-A", action='append', type=av_file_type,
               metavar='filename,language[,position[,speed]]')
```

With `nargs='+'`, it would be extremely non-trivial to format the help string the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think the things you want to happen are:

- allow the user to input 2, 3 or 4 arguments.  '+' allows that.
- tell the user how many arguments they can give.  If the code doesn't do what you want, you can always give a custom `usage`, `description`, or `help`.
- object if they enter 1 or more than 4.  You can test entries in 3 places - with a custom `type`, a custom `action`, or after `parse_args`.

`type` won't help you here, because it handles each argument separately.  If I enter `p.parse_args('-A one two three'.split())`, the `type` function is called 3 times, once for each of the argument strings.  It does not see all the strings together.

`action` might work, since it sees all the argument values that `parse_args` thinks `-A` wants.  This would all the strings between one `-A` and the next `-A` (or other flag).  But since you want to append, you need to model your custom action on the `argparse._AppendAction` class.

checking the `namespace` after the fact may be your best choice.  You'll have a list of lists, and you can check the number of elements in each of the sublists.  You can use `parse.error(your_message)` to generate an argparse style message.

There is a Python bug issue about enabling a nargs range value http://bugs.python.org/issue11354.  I proposed a patch that would accept `nargs='{m,n}'` which is modeled on the `re` feature.  In fact it ends up using `re` matching to allocated strings to various actions.  Read that issue if you want to know more about what SethMMorton is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Based on chepner's answer I developed a more advanced “subparser”:

```
audio_parameters = [ "f", "l", "p", "s", "b", "o" ]
def audio_parser(value):
    data = {
        "l": None,
        "p": -1, 
        "s": 1,
        "b": None,
        "o": 0,
    }   
    found = set()
    if value[0] in audio_parameters and value[1] == "=":
        start = 0 
        while start >= 0:
            end = start
            parameter = value[start]
            found.add(parameter)
            #search for the next ',x=' block, where x is an audio_parameter
            while end >= 0:
                # try next ',' after the last found
                end = value.find(",", end + 2)
                # exit loop, when find, (or after non found)
                if end >= 0 and value[end + 1] in audio_parameters and value[end + 1] not in found and value[end + 2] == "=":
                    end += 1
                    break
            if parameter in audio_parameters:
                parameter_value = value[start + 2:end - 1 if end > 0 else len(value)]
                if parameter_value != "":
                    data[parameter] = parameter_value
                start = end 
    else:
        i = 0 
        for splitted in value.split(","):
        if i >= len(audio_parameters):
            return ArgumentTypeError("Too many arguments")
        if len(splitted) > 0:
            data[audio_parameters[i]] = splitted
        i += 1
    if "f" in data:
        return data
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Too few arguments")
```

This allows the proposed `file[,lang[,pos[,speed]]]` but also more advanced selecting specific values. For example to set only the file, language and speed `f=file,s=speed,l=lang` does work, and this in any order. It also allows something which might look like a parameter name, but which doesn't exist or was already used. Both might have been parsed by the simple version (`f=file,x=stillname,s=speed,l=lang`). The `f` parameter there is then `file,x=stillname`. It also allows something like `f=file,f=overwrites` because it accepts only the first occurrence. So if the file name contains `,b=` you can simply write `b=,f=file,b=haha`.

A mixed mode like `file,l=lang` is not possible. And as you might have seen, that parameter got way more complex and has now 6 subparameters which makes it almost impossible to use one parameter name for each combination. And a structure like '{n,m}' is also not as flexible as you can't easily omit values.

One thing I noticed though, a metavar with [] doesn't work.